# external css color not working, but everything else is, and internal works

Tags: html, css, colors, styles

Color and background-color are not working. I have no idea what's going wrong here. I scoured this site for an answer, but no question quite applies to my situation.

I have separate html and css files, and the css file IS linked correctly in the html file. I know this because everything other than color and background-color are working as intended (font-family, margin, padding, position, display, etc).

When I change the element's color/background color via its style attribute in its opening html tag, that works. But I can't get it to work from the css file. I tried changing the height to auto and the overflow to hidden, and I tried adding the !important tag (which shouldn't matter, because nowhere else in my file so far do I try to change the color/background color of anything).

If it helps, here is this snippet of my code:

```
<div class="db-header">
    <h1 class="title">My Title</h1>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.db-header {
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: 'red';
  color: 'white';
  font-family: 'arial';
}
```

In this case, the margin becomes 100px on all size, and the font becomes arial. But no color changes. I tried writing the color as a hex code and that didn't work. I also tried using the h2's class tag, which didn't work either. I tried changing the color/background color of multiple other elements using their tags, classes, and id's as selectors, but nothing worked. I even tried changing the colors using jQuery. Any ideas? Thanks for any help.

Comment: must be `background-color:red;color: white;`

Comment: Colour names are keywords. Don't put them in quotes. Font names, however are strings and should have quotes (but single-word names are fine without them). Also side-note but worth noting that any `font-family` declaration should *always* end with `, sans-serif` (or other appropriate fallback generic font keyword (no quotes))

Comment: Thanks so much, needless to say I feel so stupid that I've been stumped by such an easy fix. Good to know about the fonts though!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from around your colours.

```
.db-header {
    margin: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'arial';
}
```